# Is there any driver jar needed to connect to cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to build a poc where back-end is cassandra and front end is j2ee. I have added the jar files available in cassandra lib folder into my java id(eclipse). But several api method is not being recognized in this context!

**Is there any driver jar for cassandra that needs to be added as in case of oracle or sybase?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cassandra jars in your j2ee. The official client side API is Thrift, here's a java example on how to connect using thrift -
http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples

there are a few java wrappers available for Thrift to connect with Cassandra (as Thrift API is not very user friendly).
Among them I can highly recommend Hector - 
http://prettyprint.me/2010/02/23/hector-a-java-cassandra-client/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Hector:
https://github.com/rantav/hector

```
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.CassandraHostConfigurator;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Cluster;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Keyspace;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.beans.HColumn;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.mutation.MutationResult;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.mutation.Mutator;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.query.ColumnQuery;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.query.QueryResult;

// sample connect method in Java
private static void connect() {
    Cluster cluster;
    Keyspace keyspace;
    StringSerializer se = new StringSerializer();
    cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160"));
    keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("Twissandra", cluster);
    Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, se)
    MutationResult rs = mutator.insert("some-name-key", "User",
    HFactory.createStringColumn("first", "some value"));
```